# Django ORM, How to join a dropped table, with multiple conditions

Tags: django, orm

```
class Post(Common):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()

class Comment(Common):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()

class Test(Common):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tester = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Category(Common):
    pass
```

I want to find a query

**(Inner JOIN test ON Test.post _id = Comment.post _id AND Test.tester_id = Comment.author_id)**

to specify two conditions for the join syntax when executing the query based on the following Comment table, but I leave a question because it is hard to find.